# Is there a MySQL equivalent of sprintf?

Tags: mysql, printf

I have an INT field in my table, which I'd like to select as a zero-padded string. So for example, 8 would come out as `008`, 23 as `023` and so on. Is this possible in a MySQL query?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're looking for the [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function:

```
SELECT LPAD(23, 3, '0'); -- '023'
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @Brad in the comments, you could also define the column with ZEROFILL:

```
`foo` INT(3) ZEROFILL
```

This would always produce at least 3 digit numbers (It would zero-pad numbers less than 3 digits, and not effect those more).  It's useful if you always need the numbers to come out like that (And not just in one query)...

Comment: As an alternative to this answer (and depending your purpose) you could add the ZEROFILL attribute to the column ( [see MySQL numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve a minimum number of padding, without cutting the results of larger numbers, you'll need to use an `IF` statement.

The example below will make sure all IDs have a minimum of three digits, while letting larger IDs still pass through untrimmed.

```
SELECT IF(id < 100, LPAD(id, 3, 0), id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of mySql you have, you could define a UDF that would format the value for you.  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html.