# Mysql "IF" in query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have few tables

```
table201202
table201203
table201204
table201205  
...
tableversion
```

In `tableversion` I have columns:
Version_ID  Admin_ID    MONTH   YEAR

I need to get something like this

```
Select *
FROM tableversion
LEFT JOIN table(tableversion.month tableversion.year) on
    table(tableversion.month tableversion.year).Version_ID=tableversion.version_id
```

But in tableversion I've got months without leading 0 so i must check if there is 5 and then change it to 05, if variable is 12 then nothing. How can I do it?

Ok, so now i have something like this

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('table',IF(tableversion.month < 10, CONCAT('0', tableversion.month ), tableversion.month ),year) as year
FROM tableversion
LEFT JOIN year ON tableversion.version_id=year.version_id WHERE ADMIN_ID=11

#1146 - Table 'database.year' doesn't exist
```

But it does not work

Comment: "When" is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: @AustinHenley if you know how can be done make a post with a sample :)

Answer (score 3):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4595083/13860), use LPAD:

> SELECT LPAD(month,2,'0') ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in the area where you're concerned about comparing the months

```
IF(tableversion.month < 10, CONCAT('0', tableversion.month), tableversion.month)
```

Comment: ok, what is wrong here? SELECT * 
FROM  `tableversion` 
JOIN CONCAT_WS('table.',IF(tableversion.month< 10, CONCAT('0', tableversion.month), tableversion.month),'tableversion.year') ON CONCAT_WS('grafik.',IF(tableversion.month < 10, CONCAT('0', tableversion.month), tableversion.month),'tableversion.year').version_id=tableversion.version_id
WHERE ADMIN_ID =11
LIMIT 10

Comment: Your initial CONCAT_WS is using table., shouldn't it be tableversion. ? Also, your original query is using table(, not table., maybe that's where I'm confused.

Comment: @breq: That should probably be another question... but... *HOW* does it not work?

Comment: It's indeed a very concerning query, I've never seen anything implemented the way he's doing it, but if he got it working before, I suppose using CONCAT_WS is not a far stretch

Comment: @Bryan Moyles, no, it must be "table." because i need to join * from for example table201204 so i need to use CONCAT_WS('table',tableversion.month,tableversion.year) :>

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting from your query? That will help me pinpoint the issue

Comment: Ok, i've almost do it `SELECT *, CONCAT('table',IF(tableversion.month < 10, CONCAT('0', tableversion.month ), tableversion.month ),year) as year
FROM tableversion
LEFT JOIN year ON tableversion.version_id=year.version_id
WHERE ADMIN_ID=11`  #1146 - Table 'database.year' doesn't exist

Comment: I've searched far and wide, and at the point, I can't find anything to do what you're trying to accomplish. I think your next best bet, is going to be to have a script create these queries dynamically. So have an array of table names established, and then dynamically set those table names inside of a looped query. I'm sorry that I couldn't take you all the way, but the answer is a bit too extensive

Answer (score 1):

I think an `IF` statement would likely perform poorly, but I have no data to back that claim.

You can try this alternative to an IF statement to achieve the same:
`SELECT *, LPAD(month, 2, '0') as month2 ....`