# PHP - how to make an insert until there is no duplicate field value exist?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have  a Mysql table where pincode field cant be duplicate daily (Sequential increment id), also i cant apply the unique key on that field using Mysql indexing for some reason.

Using PHP i am trying as below, but my code will become endless if i have to keep increasing by checking them as below.

Is there any better way without Mysql indexing to do it from PHP (zend framework)?

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total 
        FROM  `sh_av_spform` 
        WHERE  DATE(`createdate`) = CURDATE( )";
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);

if(count($result)>0) {
  $tmp_id = $result[0]['total'] +1;
  $new_id = sprintf('%03d',$tmp_id); // 009

  try{

    $sql1 = "SELECT id,pincode  
        FROM  `sh_av_spform` 
        WHERE  DATE(`createdate`) = CURDATE() and pincode='$new_id' limit 1";  
    $result1 = $db->fetchAll($sql1);
    if(count($result1)>0) {
      // 009 already exist make it 010?
      $tmp_id = $result[0]['total'] +2;
      $new_id = sprintf('%03d', $tmp_id); // 010
    }

    // Ooopsssss! 010 also exist. now what? 
    // keep wrting code forever? or there is better way?
    $db->insert('sh_av_spform', array('pincode'=>$new_id) );// Pincode cant be duplicated
```

Comment: how about insert on duplicate key update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this entirely in database, using a [counter table](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/07/01/implementing-efficient-counters-with-mysql/).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_pin (day DATE PRIMARY KEY, pin INT UNSIGNED);

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO daily_pin VALUES (CURDATE(),1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pin=LAST_INSERT_ID(pin+1);
INSERT INTO table_requiring_pin (pin) VALUES (LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),3,'0'));
COMMIT;
```

Notes:

- The counter table holds a given day's highest as yet used PIN.
- The `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` gets a new pin, either a "1" if it's the first entry for a given day, or the current value plus 1.
- `LAST_INSERT_ID`, [when given an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6153701/2908724), returns the argument and remembers it for the next time `LAST_INSERT_ID` is called *without* an argument.
- Finally, [left pad it with `LPAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595125/2908724) to get the "000" format you're wanting.

As a side benefit of this approach, you get easy metrics on pin usage. Like, "what day of the week consumes the most pin?"

Answer (score 0):

You can create one separate function for checking pin code before you insert.

For example

```
public function ValidatePinCode($PinCode){
     if(isset($PinCode)){
         $SQL=$db->prepare("SELECT pincode FROM `sh_av_spform` WHERE pincode='".$PinCode."'");
         $SQL=$db->execute($SQL);
        if($SQL->fetchColumn()>0){
            $ResponseCode='FALSE';
       }else {
            $ResponseCode='TRUE';
       }
       return $ResponseCode;
    }    
 }
```

If you get **FALSE** response then do not allow to insert new pin code else you can perform INSERT query.

Let me know if you want even more explanation on this.